# Angular 4 view not updating until second change

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to create a simple error handling in Angular 4 by showing a simple dialog with error message. However, the dialog only shows when error is set into the variable for the second time. Here is my error service (error.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {
    private errorMessage = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {

    }

    showError(error: any) {
        this.errorMessage.next({ text: error.message });
    }

    getError(): Observable<any> {
        return this.errorMessage.asObservable();
    }

    clearError() {
        this.errorMessage.next();
    }
}
```

Here is my dialog component (error.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorService } from '../../services/error.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'error',
    templateUrl: './error.component.html'
})
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    error: any;
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscription = this.errorService.getError().subscribe((error: any) => { this.showError(error); });
    }

    showError = (error: any) : void => {
        this.error = error;
    }

    clearError() {
        this.errorService.clearError();
    }

    buttonclick() {
        this.showError({text: 'this works!'});
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

And dialog view (error.component.html):

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade show" role="alert" *ngIf="error">
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="clearError()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    {{error.text}}
</div>
<button (click)="buttonclick()">testbutton</button>
```

Now, if I use the testbutton in error.component.html, everything works great. However, when I call error.service's function showError (real use case), error.component's error variable updates correctly, but view does not. When I use showError again, it now shows the previous error message. How do I update the view correctly?

**UPDATE**

ErrorService is called from globalerror.handler.ts, which overrides ErrorHandler. Code:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorService } from '../../services/error.service';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {

    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        this.errorService.showError(error);
    }
}
```

I test it by throwing an error (throw Error("ERROR");), which does not show up in the view until I throw another error. ButtonClick() is just a test, which works correctly.

Comment: Where and how do you call `errorService` to show error? It should work. Check it https://plnkr.co/edit/4Sg9NM69LICSn5iSGfFe?p=preview

Comment: on the html instead of {{error.text}} try <div *ngIf="error.text">{{error.text}}</div>

Comment: Updated question to show globalerror.handler.ts. Changing error.text to div didn't work.